# applying multiple filter ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to rotate videos and increase its sound as well as change itsframe rate

```
ffplay -i C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/Input.mp4 -af "volume="10.0",atempo="10.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/"10.0"*PTS,scale="3840:2160",fps="5.0"
```

I'm using FFmpeg as I'm trying to build a video editing application hence I need to combine many operations when i try to use above command I'm getting this error(in command im using ffplay as I just want to see output)

error

```
[atempo @ 000001fdd50c7c40] [Eval @ 00000047b79fe770] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 
'vftranspose=2'
[atempo @ 000001fdd50c7c40] Unable to parse option value "10.0 -vf transpose=2"
[atempo @ 000001fdd50c7c40] [Eval @ 00000047b79fe770] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 
 'vftranspose=2'
[atempo @ 000001fdd50c7c40] Unable to parse option value "10.0 -vf transpose=2"
[atempo @ 000001fdd50c7c40] Error setting option tempo to value 10.0 -vf transpose=2.
[Parsed_atempo_1 @ 000001fdd50c7b40] Error applying options to the filter.
Error initializing filter 'atempo' with args '10.0 -vf transpose=2'
```

Pleas help me solve this issue and suggest me a best way to add multiple operations when i try to use , its being tough so is their any other way
If yes please let me know
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing quotation marks `"` character in two places.

The following command works (weird audio, but no errors):

```
ffplay -i C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/Input.mp4 -af "volume="10.0",atempo="10.0"" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/"10.0"*PTS,scale="3840:2160",fps="5.0""
```

You don't need all the quotation marks, and you may improve readability by using `''` instead of nested `""`.
The following command is equivalent:

```
ffplay -i C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/Input.mp4 -af "volume=10.0,atempo=10.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/10.0*PTS,scale='3840:2160',fps=5.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy got it! and now I'm clear with the idea of adding multiple filter at once Thanks buddy